# Error in NbClust

Tags: r, cluster

Пытаюсь использовать кластерный анализ для данных со следующей структурой:

```
 > str(kozhgalant)
'data.frame':   184 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ sex      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age  : int  2 3 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ TV: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Job: int  1 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ Magazines   : int  1 4 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Number       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

После пришлось переформатировать данные (выдавалась ошибка сингулярности):

```
kozhgalant.num<-as.numeric(as.matrix(kozhgalant[,-6]))
NC.out<-NbClust(kozhgalant.num,method="average",index="all")
```

Но выводит ошибку:

> Error in if ((res[ncD - min_nc + 1, 14] >= resCritical[ncD - min_nc + 
>   :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: There were 50
>   or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Как такое исправить и что это вообще значит?

Comment: This forum for russian language. Please use russian, if you want to get answer.

Comment: Исправила. Ошибку, надеюсь, переводить не нужно?

Comment: Остальное переводить не нужно

Comment: Ольга, вам еще актуальна помощь? Не помешало бы дать ссылку на ваш набор данных. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269